# Android Studio 2.x - Building Symbols... Forever

Tags: android-studio

I have problem with Android Studio. After updating AS to 2.2 it takes a long (~30 min) time to process indicating that it is "Building Symbols..." The project is reasonably large and includes NDK components.

Building using gradle is quite fast:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
time: 12.089 secs
```

My gradle_wrapper settings:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
#android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries=true
#android.enableBuildCache=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m-
HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Whats wrong with Android Studio? How can I speed up it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Try changing the VM options?

It is possible your VM is running out memory or you're under memory pressure. You can try increasing the amount of memory available to Android Studio under `Help` you can choose `Edit Custom VM Options`.

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:MaxPermSize=4096m
```

#### Delete all the .idea directories and re-import the project

Close Android Studio and in the project directory and delete all .idea folders. On macOS or Linux that might be accomplished with the `find` command.

```
find . -name .idea -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Then launch Android Studio and re-import the project.

#### Switch to CMake

Android Studio's NDK support is based upon CLion which uses CMake as its project file format. I found that switching my large project to pure CMake put a permanent end to the Building Symbols problem. It makes sense, since it is probably more thoroughly tested by JetBrains and easier to support than Android.mk projects.

Comment: Thank, this solution speed up AS!

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing same issue. Last thing to try is your last point, how can I move from CLion to pure CMake?

Comment: You mean rewrite android.mk to cmakelists.txt

Comment: Removing .idea fixed it form me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was maybe caused by a large project size.

so, if Windows, go to `Program Files/Android/Android studio/bin` and find `studio.exe.vmoptions` or `studio64.exe.vmoption` files (choose 32bit or 64bit)

Last, change xmx option.

xmx option may setting 1248m, change it more than 4000 or 6000...(think your build machine ram size)

Building symbol need larger ram size than default setting.