# Android Studio 2.3.3 project, with NDK and heavy C++ dependencies, is stuck on `Building symbols`

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I have an Android Studio project with NDK C++ components, and CMake, that depends on some heavy header-only libraries like Boost. I used to mantain all the header only libraries in the folder `app/include`, but when I've decide to move all the header files to `app/src/main/cpp`, the problems started. Android Studio is completely stuck on `Buiding symbols...`.

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but unfortunately I tried every permutation of the previous solutions posted on SF, and nothing works. I erased the `.idea` file and I also increased the amount of memory available to Android Studio as suggested in this post: [Android Studio 2.x - Building Symbols... Forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640433/android-studio-2-x-building-symbols-forever)

I also disabled `Instant run` as suggested in this post: https://forum.juce.com/t/android-studio-tips-tricks-known-issues/17065

Here's the contents of the Android Studio file `studio.vmoptions`:

`-Xms512m
-Xmx6000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=500m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally ended up working for me was to move all the header only libraries (eg: boost) from `app/src/main/cpp` to `app/include`, and update my CMake file. Nothing else worked.

Also, after I moved these files, I had to click on `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`, in Android Studio.